# RaspberryPi as hotspot without internet accessed via a domain name

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, hostapd

I have a RPi set up as a hotspot (hostapd) that I use to access a web server set up on the RPi.

This RPi is not connected to the internet, it's just to serve some local pages.

I have Apache installed and so I can easily access it via a browser with the address `http://192.168.42.1`

The question is how can I use a domain to access it instead?

say I want to connect to the WiFi of the RPi (losing my internet connection) then on my browser go to http://example.com and load/redirect me to http://192.168.42.1 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hosts entry in the device from which you want to access your raspberry pi using a domain.
Let us assume your Pi's IP is 192.168.1.69
assuming the domain you want to use is local-pi.com
Example: In an ubuntu based system:
add the following lint to your /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.1.69       local-pi.com
```

In a windows based system add the following line to your C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts file:

```
192.168.1.69       local-pi.com
```

In the apache server configuration of your pi add the following line:

```
ServerAlias       local-pi.com
```